# Nginx config with React, API, and SSL getting ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR

Tags: nginx, ssl

I'm trying to set up a React app, a separate API, and SSL.
Originally, when I called from React to the API, I'd get a "Mixed Content" error in the browser console.  So I changed the app to make an https call to the API when the site was loaded over https.  Now I get this error in my chrome browser when the api is called:
`https://www.example.com:3030/authentication net::ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR`.
The rest of the site does load under https.  The react app is served on port 5000.  The api is on port 3030.

There are many similar questions on StackExchange, and I've attempted the answers they provide.  Perhaps I'm not implementing the answers correctly.   Could somebody smarter than me take a look and point me in the right direction?  Any help is gratefully received. I separated the nginx config into 2 sections in attempt to problem solve -- not sure it's a good idea.  Here's the nginx config:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  listen [::]:80;

  root path_to_build_dir;
  index index.html index.htm;
  server_name example.com;

  ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.example.com/fullchain.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.example.com/privkey.pem;
  ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.example.com/fullchain.pem;
  include /etc/nginx/snippets/ssl.conf;
  include /etc/nginx/snippets/letsencrypt.conf;

  location / {
    proxy_pass http://xxx.xx.xxx.xxx:5000;
  }

  location /authentication {
    proxy_pass http://xxx.xx.xxx.xxx:3030;
  }
}

server {
  listen 443 default_server ssl http2;
  listen [::]:443 ssl http2;

  root path_to_build_dir;
  index index.html index.htm;
  server_name example.com;

  ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.example.com/fullchain.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.example.com/privkey.pem;
  ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.example.com/fullchain.pem;
  include /etc/nginx/snippets/ssl.conf;
  include /etc/nginx/snippets/letsencrypt.conf;

  location / {
    proxy_pass http://xxx.xx.xxx.xxx:5000;
  }

  location /authentication {
    proxy_pass http://xxx.xx.xxx.xxx:3030;
  }
}
```

Thanks hugely, in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're proxying your request from port ***3030*** and ***5000*** to **https://example.com:443** 
So instead of using *https://www.example.com:3030/authentication* , 

Use **https://www.example.com/authentication**

And you don't have to specify SSL certificate on port 80 block.

 Use the below format to properly write your nginx config. You can even use the same exact code and it will work.

> Since port 80 and 443 is the standard HTTP and HTTPS port you don't
>   have to specify the port *in the browser* when you access a website
>   with https protocol at 443 port.

```
server {
  listen 80;
  listen [::]:80;
  server_name example.com www.example.com;
  return 301 https://$host$request_uri; #redirects http request to https
}

server {
  listen 443 default_server ssl http2;
  listen [::]:443 ssl http2;

  root path_to_build_dir;
  index index.html index.htm;
  server_name example.com www.example.com;
  # Make Sure your SSL certificate allows www version of your site
  # Or Else you are gonna get Certificate common name invalid error when you use www.example.com

  ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.example.com/fullchain.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.example.com/privkey.pem;
  ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.example.com/fullchain.pem;
  include /etc/nginx/snippets/ssl.conf;
  include /etc/nginx/snippets/letsencrypt.conf;

  location / {
    proxy_pass http://xxx.xx.xxx.xxx:5000;
  }

  location /authentication {
    proxy_pass http://xxx.xx.xxx.xxx:3030;
  }
}
```